# The best strategy with headers and function prototypes

Tags: c

Am relatively new in C, and I need to finish myself big C-project.. So I will define style. I am trying to figure out what is the best strategy to have a deal
with headers and function prototypes. I had been looking info.. but everything seems blurry.

So I asks. What is better approach in your experience in large C-projects?

1. Have one big header with function prototypes, and include there
   all prototype just when I add function +
       may be, separate header for structure declaration + some *.c files with structures implementation where similar function will be
   grouped.
2. Have separate header(foo.h) file with prototypes and structures
   declarations for each *.c file (foo.c)
3. To try to minimise prototypes usage by using one huge *.c file and constantly move relative to each other functions to avoid prototypes 
   at all when it it possible?

Comment: In general, I vote for #2.  Modularity makes your code easier to maintain, especially as the project grows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second choice is the typical, and generally considered the best.

In theory breaking things up into modules makes compilation faster, since you don't need to re-build code that hasn't changed, you can just link against the existing object files.

In practice linking might not be the bottleneck, but it's nice conceptually to break code into modules based on what it does. A big soup of everything in the kitchen isn't always tasty.

Answer (score 2):

1st solution would work, but prevents modularity and code reusing in other projects.

The second is what I and probably many C programmers would recommend. It allows fast compilation of projects as only changed files have to be recompiled, and can offer optimal modularity.

The third would be awful with a very big and unmaintainable file.

Answer (score 0):

***Choice two*** is the preferred method, and for good reasons:

1) ***Modularity*** - a smaller file containing functions to support a common purpose.
2) ***Maintainability*** - smaller files are easier for others to view, understand, and edit if necessary.
3) ***Code reuse*** - well written modules can be re-used in many projects

> ```
>   eg, a logging.c and logging.h, can be easily dropped into any project  
>   while everything.c and everthing.h would be useless in a new project
> ```

4) ***Efficiency of builds***. - modules, if not changed do not need to be recompiled during a build.